# For each row, which columns contain value

Tags: r

I want to look at a number of columns for each response, and if only one of those columns contains a specific string then put that column name into a new column.

Example dataframe:

```
data <- structure(list(ParticipantID = 1:5, Usual = c("Pear", "Pear", 
"Apple", NA, NA), Pear_Freq = c("3 or more times a week", "3 or more times a week", 
"Once a week", "Once a week", "3 or more times a week"), Apple_Freq = c("Never", 
"Once a week", "3 or more times a week", "Never", "3 or more times a week"
), Peach_Freq = c("Once a week", "Never", "Never", "3 or more times a week", 
"Once a week")), .Names = c("ParticipantID", "Usual", "Pear_Freq", 
"Apple_Freq", "Peach_Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

So what I would be hoping to get out of it would a new column containing:

```
ParticipantID   Newcol
1               Pear
2               Pear
3               Apple
4               Peach
5               NA
```

(As a way of checking if what people said and did matches up, and to fill in blanks in the 'usual' column)

So far, I have some code which puts a count into a new column, so that I can select people who only ticked 3 or more times a week in one column (not 2, or 0):

```
test$tempcol <- NA
test$tempcol <- apply(test[,Freqcols], 1, function(x) sum(grepl("3 or more times a week", x)))
```

(I feel like I don't need to use `grepl` for this, since I'm looking to match the whole cell not a pattern, really)

And then I was trying to use which to get the index of the columns for each respondent which contains "3 or more times a week" something like this:

```
which(apply(test, 1, function(x) any(grepl("3 or more times a week", x))))
```

But of course, that just tells me that everyone said 3 or more times a week for at least one column.

And then I was hoping to use that to paste the Fruit bit of the column title into a new cell, but I'm a bit lost on how to actually get to that bit :( any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
data$newcol <- apply(data[3:5], 1, function(x) 
   ifelse(length(which(x == "3 or more times a week")) != 1, NA,
   unlist(strsplit(names(data[3:5])[which(x == "3 or more times a week")], "_")))[1])

#  ParticipantID Usual              Pear_Freq             Apple_Freq             Peach_Freq newcol
#1             1  Pear 3 or more times a week                  Never            Once a week   Pear
#2             2  Pear 3 or more times a week            Once a week                  Never   Pear
#3             3 Apple            Once a week 3 or more times a week                  Never  Apple
#4             4  <NA>            Once a week                  Never 3 or more times a week  Peach
#5             5  <NA> 3 or more times a week 3 or more times a week            Once a week   <NA>
```

You would start checking the frequency of the response being "3 or more times a week" with `which` and if it occurs more or less than once, you would return `NA`. If it occurs only once, `which` will tell you the index of the columns where it occurs and you use `names(data[3:5])` to find out the matching column names. To get only the fruit bit of the name you split it by "_", `unlist` the resulting list and use the first bit of it only to write into the new column.

Comment: How can I modify this to work if "3 or more times a week" doesn't occur in a row?  Do I need to nest another ifelse?

Comment: Just change the `>1` in the `ifelse` to `!=1`. Does that work?

Comment: o.O  yes it does!  OH I UNDERSTAND!!  I'm so sorry, I had it round the wrong way in my head :)  Thank you so much for your help!